# In Worldwar, what was the Fourth planet the Race decided not to conquer?

Tags: harry-turtledove, worldwar-series, colonization-series

In the Worldwar and Colonization novels, Harry Turtledove posits that the Race conquered and colonized two planets before setting its sights on Earth.

In addition, it is mentioned that at some previous point a probe had been sent to a *fourth* planet, but it was determined to be to inhospitable and plans for conquest were abandoned.

What was this fourth star system/planet? Has Turtledove ever commented on it, or have other works mentioned it?

Comment: Is [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138957/51379) you?

Comment: [Mars](http://turtledove.wikia.com/wiki/Mars#Mars_in_Worldwar)?

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is nothing more than a single mention of a planet being "too cold" in general to be colonised by The Race. The Turtledove wiki seems to confirm this.